# dygraph: synchronization example

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I’m a bioengineer and I have to admit I have no experience with js. I’m using Dygraph to create a few graphs and I need to synchronize the zoom on them, so I check the example ‘synchronization’ in the gallery. It says I have to source extras/synchronizer.js on your page. When I click on it I end up in a page saying: 404 this is not the page you were looking for.

Another problem, when I create a graph I get this error notifications:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/programs/progettoprovaG/averageV.csv. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
>   dygraph-combined-dev.js:5428 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute
>   'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/programs/progettoprovaG/averageV.csv'.

By the way this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_average_breath_volume" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
    <div id="div_average_breath_impedence" style="width:600px; height:300px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var highlight_start = 55;
        var highlight_end = 65;

        // grafico del volume + sd
        v = new Dygraph(
                document.getElementById("div_average_breath_volume"),
        "averageV.csv",
        {
            labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
            labels: ["s","L"],
            errorBars: true,
            title: 'average breath', 
            ylabel: 'volume [L]',
            xlabel: 'time [s]',
            animatedZooms: true,
            underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, v) {
                var bottom_left = v.toDomCoords(highlight_start);
                var top_right = v.toDomCoords(highlight_end);
                var left = bottom_left[0];
                var right = top_right[0];
                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 102, 1.0)";
                canvas.fillRect(left, area.y, right - left, area.h);
            }
        }
                );
        z = new Dygraph(
                document.getElementById("div_average_breath_impedence"),
        "averageZ.csv",
        {
            errorBars: true,
            labelsDivStyles: { 'textAlign': 'right' },
            legend: 'always',
            labels: ["s","R","X"],
            ylabel: 'impedence [L]',
            xlabel: 'time [s]',
            animatedZooms: true,
            underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, z) {
                var bottom_left = z.toDomCoords(highlight_start);
                var top_right = z.toDomCoords(highlight_end);
                var left = bottom_left[0];
                var right = top_right[0];
                canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 102, 1.0)";
                canvas.fillRect(left, area.y, right - left, area.h);
            }
        }
                );     
    }
            );
        </script>
</body>
```

Something similar happens when I try to simply execute an example from the Dygraph gallery:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>   dygraph-combined-dev.js:5428 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/programs/progettoprovaG/twonormals.csv. Cross
>   origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
>   chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
>   dygraph-combined-dev.js:5428 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute
>   'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/programs/progettoprovaG/twonormals.csv'.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

to fix the crossorigin request
you need to serve your files, e.g.,
run

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

in the directory with your code,
and open

```
localhost:8000
```

in your browser

Answer (score -1):

I just discovered Dygraphs and synchronizer and started using them.
I had same problems as you finding a working synchronizer.js and found one that worked but had a little issue.
Searching a good hour on Stackoverflow and Github, i finaly could correct the bug and now it seems to works like a charm !

On [my test page](http://www.egloff.eu/apaguard/test1.php), you can download it from my test example.

Can't help with your second problem... Sorry.